# Magento backend not working for admin users after server move

Tags: admin, backend

Just moved to a new server, everything seem to went fine. The only thing is that any users with "admin" rights on the back-end of Magento just see the image below but staff are fine who dont have administrative permeations in back-end. Ho could I debug this!!  [image]

Comment: View the end of the page source, looks like an early script termination because of an error

Answer (score 0):

Set developer mode to true and set display errors to 1 in `index.php`

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It should tell you what the error is

Comment: Mines already set to that

Answer (score 0):

This is normal permission error.
1. Clear cache in /var/cache/*
2. Set default permission for your site on new server then try again.

Comment: Hi there how do you set default permissions for your site

Comment: If you  have SSH access, let try this:

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod +x mage

Comment: Hi there I chmod the whole directory with 777 permission for the mean time, still have no luck with that. Is that what your saying?